# How do I remove line references in generate output in doxygen?

Tags: doxygen

I want to remove lines look as follows but I still want to return source code browsing

```
Definition at line 377 of file xxx.h.
```

I have tried the following two in the doxygen config file but these just remove cross references on types

```
# If the REFERENCES_RELATION tag is set to YES 
# then for each documented function all documented entities 
# called/used by that function will be listed.

REFERENCES_RELATION    = NO

# If the REFERENCES_LINK_SOURCE tag is set to YES (the default) 
# and SOURCE_BROWSER tag is set to YES, then the hyperlinks from 
# functions in REFERENCES_RELATION and REFERENCED_BY_RELATION lists will 
# link to the source code.  Otherwise they will link to the documentation.

REFERENCES_LINK_SOURCE = NO
```

**update**: I've just trying setting the following and seems to do the jobs but waiting to confirm if this is the correct way of achieving what I want

```
SOURCE_BROWSER         = NO
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Got it

SOURCE_BROWSER         = NO

Answer (score 2):

documentation also mention

> To get rid of all source code in the generated output, make sure also
>   VERBATIM_HEADERS is set to NO.